# Custom 404 page with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect to an html page when a 404 error is thrown. I have a folder titled: 404 in my public folder. Here is the code in the index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.route('/me').get(function(req, res){

res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/html/contacts.html')


})

app.use(function(req, res, next){

// res.type('txt').send('Not found');
// res.status(404).end('error');

  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('404', { url: req.url });
    return;
  }

});



var server = app.listen(8000, function(){

console.log("Server is happening %s", server.address().port);

});
```

But I get the following error:

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/pi/server/index.js:19:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /home/pi/server/index.js:19:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/pi/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)

Comment: if you found any of the answers useful to you, you should consider upvoting and choosing the best one.

Answer (score 3):

In case you can adapt your `404` page to be a static page, you can simply do (from [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status)):

```
res.status(404).sendFile('/path/to/404.html');
```

Conversely, if you want to have some view model object to be rendered (e.g., `{url: req.url}`), you have to decide for a template engine (e.g., Jade, EJS, Handlebars). As an example, assuming you want to use jade, you first install it as a dependency:

```
npm install jade
```

Then, you should add the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```
app.set('view', path.join(__dirname, 'private/view/path'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Once the template engine is in place, you can do:

```
res.render('viewName', viewModelObject)
```

and the `viewName` will be resolved as `./private/view/path/viewName.jade`. Hence, assuming the existence of `./private/view/path/404.jade`, you can do:

```
res.render('404', { url: req.url });
```

Please remember to keep your templates (i.e., your `.jade` files) somewhere inaccessible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

for response.render method, you have to use template engine like ejs.

and you have to setup view options.

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

But if you have put 404 file in public folder, then you can simply use sendfile or redirect to static path.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });
```

Comment: 404 should not be an exceptions. This is an abuse of the throw catch model. You have caught the 404 in a 404 specific function why would you route it through 500+ error handling?